# Problem with H5Py with Tensorflow and Keras in R

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, h5py

I have always the same error message in R and no idea how to solve. I use Tensoflow 1.15, Keras 2.2 and Python 3.7.

```
> setwd("C:/Users/PC/Desktop/AI defect/models/")
> model <- load_model_hdf5("my_model_W_AI defect.h5")
Error in load_model_hdf5("my_model_W_AI defect.h5") : 
  The h5py Python package is required to save and load models
```

Here the code:

```
> library(usethis)
> library(devtools)
> library(reticulate)
> Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(Sys.getenv('PATH'), "C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/", sep = ';'))
> Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(Sys.getenv('PATH'), "C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/Scripts", sep = ';'))
> Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(Sys.getenv('PATH'), "C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/Lib/site-packages/h5py", sep = ';'))
> Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(Sys.getenv('PATH'), "C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/Lib/site-packages/tensorflow", sep = ';'))
> use_condaenv("r-reticulate", required = TRUE)
> library(tensorflow)
> library(keras)
> reticulate::py_config()
python:         C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/python.exe
libpython:      C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/python37.dll
pythonhome:     C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate
version:        3.7.9 (default, Aug 31 2020, 17:10:11) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:          C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/Lib/site-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  1.19.1
tensorflow:     C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\R-MINI~1\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.p

NOTE: Python version was forced by use_python function
> tf$constant("Hellow Tensorflow")
2020-09-13 14:44:10.962504: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_100.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_100.dll not found
2020-09-13 14:44:10.962504: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
Tensor("Const:0", shape=(), dtype=string)
```

Comment: Have you installed `h5py` package to your Python?

Comment: If I installed h5py from Conda in r-reticulate env, I have new this message: Warning! ***HDF5 library version mismatched error  and then R-studio crash. Do I need to install a specific version ?